# Return the exposed callable page handler that is used for a route

Tags: cherrypy

Using the simple application:

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/')
```

Is there a way I can hook into the dispatching process and get the name of which handler is to be called? In this instance, when I go to `/`, I want to be able to print `index` or whatever the name of the exposed method for that route is. It seems like a `before_handler` or `before_finalize` hook would be what I want, but not clear how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `before_handler` hook, I was able to retrieve it through `request.handler.callable`